# Question regarding publishing Android application into Android market

Tags: android

I'll be publishing an Android application to the market for the first time .
I have already posted all these questions on the Android Market help website but no one answered , hence posting the question here though I know this is a developer forum , since I dont know of anyother option of getting answers to this question.

I have the following queries:

1> I want to publish the application in my organisation's name , so do I need to visit the http://market.android.com/publish & create a mail Id in my company's name ?

2> Do I need to provide an authorisation letter in my organisation's name , if I am publishing the application in my organisation's name ?

3> Is there any separate licence for a developer publishing an Android application & an organisation publishing an application?

4> Is there any renewal policy of the licence?

5> I want to use the application from an enterprise perpective , so want to know is there any rule for the same.

I went through the developer site of android , but didn't find any information about publishing an Android application in Android market in the name of the organisation. Everything mentioned there seems for an individual developer perspective.

Kindly provide me your inputs. Sorry if I posted it at wrong place.

Warm Regards,

CB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Publishing an Android app has very little restrictions. Briefly:

1> Yes, you need to create an account and pay a $25 fee. It's makes sense to have the email address reflect the company name, but it's not necessary.

2-4> No authorization letter is required nor is there any special license that's granted, so there's no renewal required.

5> There's nothing special with regards to enterprise use. However note that once you publish on the market, anyone can install and run your application (within the geographic and device capability limits specified when you publish and in the manifest).

Note, for enterprise use, you may want to consider not publishing to the market and simply installing the .apk from a local file server. This is pretty straight forward. You just need to enable "Unknown sources" in the Application settings and download the .apk using your browser (or you can get use a QR code and a scanner app).

Comment: Unfortunately, AT&T disables Unknown Sources. So, how would an enterprise be able to distribute an app to AT&T phones without them installing the Android SDK?